# Output column salary already exists in pyspark Vector Assembler

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I'm using pyspark 3.0.1. I'm going to develop a linear regression model with salary as dependent variable & around 79 independent variables
So I wrote following code

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler, StandardScaler
train,test=df.randomSplit([0.7,0.3],seed=21)
input_col=[...]
vector_assembler=VectorAssembler(inputCols=input_col,outputCol='salary')
temp_train=vector_assembler.transform(train)
```

Bit I'm getting following error in temp_train execution step,

```
IllegalArgumentException: Output column salary already exists.
```

But salary is not there in my input_col list. Can you suggest me how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: It already exists in your dataframe, so you may want to drop that column beforehand

Comment: @mck, are you saying I need to drop salary from my train data frame?

Comment: yes you're right